# Summing over the elements of a group $G$. Can someone explain how are these two expressions equal?

Tags: group-theory

Say $\rho$ and $\pi$ are two group homomorphism, $G$ is a non-abelian group and $x$ a fixed element of $G$.

It is written without explanation that $$\sum_{g\in G} \rho(xg)\pi(g^{-1})$$ can be equivalently formulated as $$\sum_{gx\in G}\rho(gx)\pi((xg)^{-1}x).$$ I realize that the index can be changed from $g$ to $gx$ because all the elments of $G$ are covered this way as well. Moreover, I can see that $(xg)^{-1}x = g^{-1}$. What I don't get is how come $xg$ inside of $\rho$ is now changed to $gx$?

Edit: I have run into a similar problem before and I couldn't find the solution there as well. The problem is that $$\sum_{g\in G} \rho(gx) \pi(g)=\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)\pi(x^{-1}g).$$ This time, the index remains $g\in G$ in both the sums but the rest I don't follow. It is mentioned that we are using the bijection that sends $g$ to $gx$.

Comment: Both seem to be wrong. First of all I don't understand what "$gx\in G$" index is supposed to mean. Secondly in the first equation we can use $g\mapsto x^{-1}gx$ bijection to obtain $\sum_{g\in G}\rho(gx)\pi(x^{-1}gx)$. In the second equation we use $g\mapsto gx^{-1}$ bijection to obtain $\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)\pi(gx^{-1})$ on the right side. These **are not** equal to the written sums.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. The $(xg)^{-1}$ should be $(gx)^{-1}$. Turn the first sum into the second by replacing $g$ with $x^{-1}gx$. If $g$ varies over all elements of $G$ then so do the conjugates $x^{-1}gx$; this just re-indexes the terms (permutes the summands). Unless $x$ is supposed to be a central element or something?

Comment: @runway44 I am thinking as well that it's perhaps a typo. I don't know if the second equation is written incorrectly also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g$ is a dummy variable. In particular, if you call
$$h=xgx^{-1}$$
so that $g=x^{-1}hx$.
Then, substituting $g=x^{-1}hx$ you get
$$\sum_{g \in G} \rho (xg) \pi (g^{-1}) = \sum_{h \in G} \rho (x(x^{-1}hx)) \pi ((x^{-1}hx)^{-1})$$
which is equal to
$$\sum_{h \in G} \rho (hx) \pi (x^{-1}h^{-1}x)$$
Now, $h$ is a dummy variable, so you can write again $g$ instead of $h$.

Comment: So you're also saying that with $gx$ inside of $\rho$, it's impossible to get just $g^{-1}=(xg)^{-1}x$ inside of $\pi$?

Comment: I think you are perhaps right and it would make sense because after reading further into this paper, I realize that with $(xg)^{-1}$ the claim the author is trying to prove doesn't follow, but it does with $(gx)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not true.
Let $G=S_3$, $x=(1\,2)$, and $\rho(g)=1$ if $g=(2\,3)$ and $=0$ otherwise, and $\pi$ any function with $\pi\bigl((1\,3\,2)\bigr)\ne\pi\bigl((1\,2\,3)\bigr)$.
Then the first sum is 
$$\sum_{g\in G} \rho(xg)\pi(g^{-1})=\sum_{g=(1\,2\,3)} \rho(xg)\pi(g^{-1})=\rho\bigl((2\,3)\bigr)\pi\bigl((1\,3\,2)\bigr)=\pi\bigl((1\,3\,2)\bigr)$$
whereas the second sum is
$$\sum_{gx\in G}\rho(gx)\pi((xg)^{-1}x)=\sum_{gx=(2\,3)}\rho(gx)\pi((xg)^{-1}x)
=\sum_{g=(1\,3\,2)}\rho(gx)\pi((xg)^{-1}x)=\pi\bigl((1\,2\,3)\bigr). $$

Comment: $\rho$ and $\pi$ are supposed to be representations of $G$. I omitted writing it because I thought it wasn't relevant and I assumed the expressions were true so didn't think there would be a counter example.